# Jackson scala object mapper not properly serializing nested case class

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a schema which is defined like this

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = classOf[ProductDeserializer])
trait GenericProduct{
  @JsonUnwrapped
  def commonAttributes: CommonAttributes
}
```

There are different kinds of products. For example, Product A given below extends base trait Product. Similarly, there are other products B, C, D.

```
case class ProductA(commonAttributes: CommonAttributes,
                    extraField1: String,
                    extraField2: String) extends GenericProduct
```

My serializer method is like this

```
@Component
class ProductSerializer @Autowired()
(val mapper: ScalaObjectMapper = ObjectMapperSingleton.getMapper) {

    def serialize[T<:GenericProduct](product: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): String = {
        mapper
          .writerWithType[T]
          .writeValueAsString(product)
      }
}
```

If i pass objects of type A, B, C, D, it works just fine. Serialized JSON string has common attributes and product specific attributes.

But if i wrap the product objects inside a case class. For example, from one method i'm returning something like this

```
case class ConsolidatedProducts(newProducts: List[GenericProduct],
                                oldProducts: List[GenericProduct])
```

It doesn't complain during compile time but during runtime the output have only the common attributes.

Question: Is this because of type erasure?
If I pass the manifest implicitly to all the places where the consolidatedProducts is called and used, then i can see the expected JSON with all the attributes which makes me believe this is because of type erasure.

Found two ways to solve this

1. Use manifest implicitly everywhere to retain type information
2. Just update `writerWithType[T]` to `writerWithType[T.type]`

Is there any other workaround? I'm still not sure why the second solution works. If someone can explain, that would be great.

Comment: Just so you know, `Product` is the name of a Scala [auto-imported trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Product.html). Probably unrelated, but could cause some nasty issues.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. Just used a fake name.

Comment: @erip updated the class name